# What does ripiamo mean?

Tags: meaning

While going through some photos of when we were in Rome when Italy won the World Cup in 2006, I saw a banner reading

> Vi aspettavamo da 6 anni… e mo se ripiamo pure la Gioconda

We get the reference to the Italy/France game from 6 years prior, and the Mona Lisa, but what does *ripiamo* mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Ripiamo* (or *ripijamo*) is a way to write the Roman form for what in Standard Italian is *ripigliamo*, the first person plurale of the verb [*ripigliare*](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ripigliare), that is, “to take again” or, as in this case, “to take back”.

So, the meaning would be that, just as Italy took the cup “from” France, beating them in the final, so, in the intention of the writer, Italy would have taken back an important Italian masterpiece hosted in a French museum.

(I should perhaps add that *se* is Roman as well, corresponding to Standard Italian *ci*. You can find [here](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8667/when-is-a-sentence-like-mi-sono-mangiato-una-pizza-ai-quattro-formaggi-used) something about this non-compulsory use of a pronoun with some verbs.)